# ajax connection with php not working at subdirectory

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello I have a javascript file in the directory

> root/ assets/ js / a.js

and a php file  at the directory

> root/php/foo.php

At the a.js file I am trying to use ajax in order to connect with the foo.php . If the a foo.php is located at the root directory a.k.a

```
root/foo.php
```

the function works fine but when i put the file in the directory above nothing works. Here is the function associated with the connection

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
           alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","../../studentSignupPHP/test.php?q=" + str, true);
```

The relative path at the

```
 xmlhttp.open(..)
```

seems fine to me,so I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Can you help me?

foo.php

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

Comment: You tagged your question as `jquery`. Why don't you use jQuery's ajax implementation?

Comment: @MightyPork oops that's a mistake. I don't know the "translation" of this function to jquery. I am new to webdesign. I'll remove the tag of jquery to avoid misconceptions.

Comment: the path is dependent on the page you are loading in browser, not where the js file is stored. Open your browser dev tools and look at network tab, will see the path browser is trying to use for the ajax call

Comment: @JmRag in jquery, it's just `$.ajax({...options...});`. Super easy and solid.

Comment: path is not set correctly, give the correct path to foo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than traversing from the js directory, use a reference to the root path like so

> /php/foo.php

See charlietfl's comment above for the reason why.

*Edit:* *Updated with comments from @charlietfl*

*"the path is dependent on the page you are loading in browser, not where the js file is stored. Open your browser dev tools and look at network tab, will see the path browser is trying to use for the ajax call"*

Comment: yes it works! I understood why from the comments above.

Comment: You must edit your post and put it there crediting @charlietfl.Its not good to throw pointers on comments for explanation